# file_put_contents could not store image on server

Tags: php, facebook

```
$path = 'http://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/372096_100002534902767_1927052265_n.jpg';
$info = file_put_contents('new/angel.jpg', file_get_contents(urldecode($path)));
echo $info;
```

It works fine on `localhost` but it did not work on my website.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 3):

- Check your logs for error messages
- Does the folder ("new") exist?
- Are permissions set to allow writing by scripts?
- Are you sure the error is in file_put_contents? file_get_contents could fail if the host has disallowed url_fopen.
- unless $path is actually hardcoded, you will probably introduce an arbitrary file disclosure security issue. Make sure you validate your input.

Comment: other image file is dynamically generated my imagecreatefromjpeg() or merge pic to create new image file and store it on web server.

Comment: Then continue to check the other points... e.g. if `echo strlen(file_get_contents(urldecode($path)));` doesn't return the correct file size, then file_get_contents probably doesn't work. Have you enabled warnings? `error_reporting(E_ALL)` should be in all your scripts during development.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give a permission (write ) to upload folder

you can do that by the FTP program by using this codes in numeric value :777

Comment: or just use the chmod()-method from php

Comment: i don't know how to set permission of writing for server but think write permissions are ok because i already dynamically created image file from other php functions.

Comment: what the FTP client you are using ?

Comment: right click on the folder select the last option (file permissions ) then write 777

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that there are write permissions to the file in which you are writing
2. I think the relative path is the problem. It can possible that your local has the path to that file but the path does not exists on server.
   3.Please  put a forward slash in line `$info=file_put_contents('new/angel.jpg', file_get_contents(urldecode($path)))`; before your "new" folder and try i think this might be a problem

Comment: do not use forward slash please, unless you are hosting on IIS (if you don't know, you are not)

Comment: my other folder images is work fine and store images dynamically created by function imagecreatefromjpeg().